# How to custom donut thickness using c3.js?

Tags: javascript, charts, c3.js

I would like to customize a donut chart from c3.js for example the arc thickness.

Any help or pointers are greatly appreciated.

[image: C3.js Donut arc thickness]

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['Data1', 30],
            ['Data2', 50],
        ],
        type : 'donut'
    },
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ktjhh5qr/1/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can find an example [here](http://c3js.org/samples/chart_donut.html).

```js
var chart = c3.generate({
  data: {
    columns: [
      ['bulls', 30],
      ['lakers', 50],
    ],
    type : 'donut',
  },
  donut: { width: 100 }
})
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ktjhh5qr/2/